# Network Hub to Hub - no network

Tags: networking, router, switch, pfsense, hub

I've set up a home network using hubs. I know it's best to replace hubs with network switches however the hubs were donated and it's not feasible to buy network switches. 
The setup consists of a hub (hub 1) connected to the firewall and then another hub (hub 2) is connected to hub 1. 
If I connect the 2 hubs directly to each other with cat5 cables, data flows from hub 1 to hub 2. 
The problem is that, when I place the 2 hubs in different rooms (connected through) wall ports, data doesn't flow from hub 1 to hub 2.
 
Weirdly enough, if I replace hub 2 with a laptop, the laptop has no problem receiving data and successfully connects to hub 1.

To explain further the issue are the images attached.[image] 
*The image above shows the setup that works*.
[image]

*The image above shows the setup that doesn't works*

For assurance I've tried replacing the hub with another one and also I've tried several different ports on the hub.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. 
Many thanks in advance
J

Answer (score 3):

Try a crossover cable.  Make sure that your wall ports are straight thru.

Nothing wrong with a hub system, as long as there is only a couple users.  Basically, more users, the slower the network or if you are downloading a large file, then the other computers are going to crawl.

Comment: Indeed. As for *"if I replace hub 2 with a laptop, the laptop has no problem receiving data and successfully connects to hub 1"*: modern network equipment (as used in the laptop) doesn't really care about cross cables any more, and will auto-detect the cable type. But maybe the old hubs don't. So it seems the problem is non-straight wiring in the wall ports. A crossover cable between the wall outlet and hub 2 can fix that odd wiring, if fixing the wall outlets is too hard. (Assuming all cables are straight cables right now...)

Comment: Just in case it helps, @joebegborg07, see [How to tell a Ethernet cable is conventional or crossover](http://superuser.com/questions/244583/how-to-tell-a-ethernet-cable-is-conventional-or-crossover). And of course rather than using a crossover cable from the wall to hub 2, you could also use one from hub 1 to the wall instead.