# Share WiFi to Ethernet

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ethernet

How do I share my wireless internet to another computer directly connected with ethernet from both end ? no router whatsoever.
I've tried the sharing tab but the local area connection doesn't get an internet despite already being shared from wireless [my network and sharing center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3VF5.png)

I have tried this one, which is the answer in other superuser question like mine
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PJi6.jpg (I also want to learn how you guys post pictures here like in the forums with [img][/img])

When I tried this one the LAN shows 'No Internet Access'.
The 'Home networking connection:' was Local Area Connection, I've just switched it to wireless 2 for now and unplugged the ethernet cable as it is currently useless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 7 share internet connection with multiple network interfaces](https://superuser.com/questions/656998/windows-7-share-internet-connection-with-multiple-network-interfaces)

Comment: If you want to connect 2 computers NICs (network interface card) directly (with no router), you have to use a crossover ethernet cable.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/244583/how-to-tell-a-ethernet-cable-is-conventional-or-crossover 'How to tell a Ethernet cable is conventional or crossover.
In the 4th comment, is the user talking about ethernet card as in mobo's nic or modem's  ? if it's the former, how can I make my motherboard recognize the cable as crossover ? . It's my first time knowing that not all ethernet cable is the same.

Comment: After doing a little more research, it appears my understanding connecting 2 PCs directly together may be a bit outdated.  You might be able to use a straight-through ethernet cable if your NICs are new enough (gigabit). Did you check out the link @music2myear shared?  You might need to set a static IP for the wired adapter in the host PC.

Comment: My nic supports gigabit and the link doesn't solve my problem as I just need to share my wireless to a single lan. The normal sharing tab works but the internet doesn't flow to ethernet cable. Do I have to edit something in my nic driver manually to make it work like a crossover ?

Comment: Cable type detection on gigabit adapters is automatic.  I think you need to bridge the LAN adapters on the host before you share with the sharing tab on the wifi adapter (see answer #1 on the link above).  The second answer mentions they had to set a static IP address on the bridge connection to make it work.  I don't have a comparable PC setup to test.  Sorry I can't give you a more definitive answer.

Comment: I don't really have any idea how to set an IP into static or even check if a specific ip is static or not
I do ipconfig /all. see all my ips but don't really know what to look for